# mvc 3 The model item passed into the dictionary is of type A but this dictionary requires a model item of type B

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am getting the following error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '...Models.VideoPostingModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type '...Models.RegisterModel'.
```

I am not sure what the issue is because the models match up...

Controller:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using stayyolo.Models;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data;

```
...Controllers
{
    public class VidsPostingController : Controller
    {

        private dbEntities db = new dbEntities();
        //
        // GET: /VidsPosting/



        public ActionResult Details(Guid id)
        {
            Posting posting = db.Postings.Find(id);
            if (posting.Image == null)
            {
                posting.Image = new byte[0];
                db.Entry(posting).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            //convert ENTITY MODEL CLASS TO Model
            VideoPostingModel toRet = new VideoPostingModel();
            toRet.linkIfVideo = posting.LinkIfVideo;
            toRet.PostDate = posting.PostDate;
            toRet.Titile = posting.Titile;
            toRet.TypeOfPosting = posting.TypeOfPosting;
            return View(toRet);
        }

}
```

Model:

```
public class VideoPostingModel
{
    ..Variables

    public VideoPostingModel()
    {
        ...

    }
}


View: 

@model ...Models.VideoPostingModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<fieldset>
    <legend>Posting</legend>
    <div class="display-label">
        Description</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="display-label">
        Title</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Titile)
    </div>
    <div class="display-label">
        Post Date</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PostDate)
    </div>
    <div class="display-label">
        Type Of Posting</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TypeOfPosting)
    </div>
</fieldset>


        <div id="youtubePlayerdiv"">
        <p style="text-align: justify">
        Video!</p>
        <iframe  id="youtubePlayer" class="youtube-player" type="text/html"
        width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<%=Model.LinkIfVideo%>" frameborder="0">
        </iframe>
        </div>
        <!-- end youtubeplayerDiv div -->
```

I very much appreciate the help in advance, issue occurs right when the website hits the details method of the controller.

Comment: is it all code?? Can you show RegisterModel?

Comment: the ResgisterModel is just the basic MVC standard model you get when you create the porject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting implies that somewhere on your view or _Layout you have tried to render another partial like this:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Account/Register.cshtml")
```

But this partial requires a different model - `RegisterModel`. So one possibility is to pass a new instance of this model to the partial when rendering it:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Account/Register.cshtml", new RegisterModel())
```

Comment: This was not the issue, But I just used an akward solutions and passed all the data through the view bag. Thanks you!

Comment: But let me know if you come up with a reason for it... it is weird-- i cant use models now...